# How to disable google instant search in Twebbrowser?

Tags: internet-explorer

I would like to make use of the search parameters that google search interprets such as "num=100". This will not work unless instant search is disabled in the browser. I am using twebbrowser how can I turn off instant search?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its on your preferences page:

http://www.google.com/preferences

Comment: I was hoping for a way to do this programatically. Thanks anyways.

Comment: For what? internet-explorer as you tagged, or twebbrowser?